# PyQt4's udp broadcast doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, udp, pyqt4, broadcast

My application written in PyQt4 doesn't seem to get any data.
readyRead event isn't even fired.
Use of the applications is following:

```
python server.py -s -p 50000 #(server on port 50000)
python server.py -c -p 50000 #(client sending data to port 50000)
```

//

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt4 import QtNetwork, QtCore
from optparse import OptionParser

class Server(object):

    def __init__(self, port):

        self.port = port

        try:
            self.socket = QtNetwork.QUdpSocket()
            self.socket.bind(QtNetwork.QHostAddress.Broadcast, int(self.port), QtNetwork.QUdpSocket.ShareAddress)

            self.socket.readyRead.connect(self.receiver)

        except QtNetwork.QUdpSocket.NetworkError:
            print "EXCEPTION DURING INITIALIZING SERVER'S SOCKET"
            sys.exit(1)

    def receiver(self):
        print "DEBUG: RECEIVE"
        while(self.socket.hasPendingDatagrams()):
            try:
                size = self.socket.pendingDatagramSize()
                msg, host, port = self.socket.readDatagram(size)
            except:
                print "EXCEPTION DURING RECEIVEING AND READING DATAGRAM"
            else:
                print "HOST %s:%s MSG: %s" % (str(host), str(port), str(msg))

    def __del__(self):
        print "DESTRUCTOR"
        self.socket.close()

class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, port):

        self.port = port

        try:
            self.socket = QtNetwork.QUdpSocket()
        except:
            print "EXCEPTION DURING INITIALIZING CLIENT'S SOCKET"

        self.main_loop()

    def main_loop(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.debug_msg()
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print "EXITING"
        self.socket.close()


    def debug_msg(self):
        msg = "DEBUG"
        self.socket.writeDatagram(msg, QtNetwork.QHostAddress.Broadcast, int(self.port))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-p", "", action="store", type="string", dest="port")
    parser.add_option("-c", "", action="store_true", dest="client")
    parser.add_option("-s", "", action="store_true", dest="server")

    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    if not (options.server or options.client):
        print "Client/Server not specified. Could not continue..."
        sys.exit(1)

    elif not options.port:
        print "Server's port not specified. Could not continue..."
        sys.exit(1)

    else:

        if options.server:
            serv = Server(options.port)

            App = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
            sys.exit(App.exec_())
        else:
            client = Client(options.port)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client, you are not starting Qt's event loop. You should allocate an application object and either call exec_ on it and handle the debug_msg calls via timers or you should pump the event loop using QCoreApplication.processEvents().

Another option is to use flush():

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractsocket.html#flush

> `bool QAbstractSocket::flush ()`
>
> This function writes as much as possible from the internal write
>   buffer to the underlying network socket, without blocking. If any data
>   was written, this function returns true; otherwise false is returned.
>
> Call this function if you need QAbstractSocket to start sending
>   buffered data immediately. The number of bytes successfully written
>   depends on the operating system. In most cases, you do not need to
>   call this function, because QAbstractSocket will start sending data
>   automatically once control goes back to the event loop. In the absence
>   of an event loop, call waitForBytesWritten() instead.

Answer (score 0):

`QtNetwork.QUdpSocket.NetworkError` is not a exception type, but just a constant. And, why do bind the socket to `QHostAddress.Broadcast`. Do you need the `QHostAddress.Any` instead?